# Redirecting From Middleware In Laravel Is Not Working As Expected

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, redirect, middleware

I am working on an react-laravel project and i am trying to protect the dashboard routes with a middleware, here is the code from the middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $apiToken = $request->bearerToken();
    $isAuthenticated = User::where('api_token', $apiToken)
                            ->where('is_admin', true)
                            ->first();

    if(!$isAuthenticated) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Now the problem is in case of the user is not authenticated the middleware does not redirect to the desired route, instead it returns the html page as text in the response as follows.[Response in case of of not authenticated user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE2GE.png)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/css/app.css">
        <title>Some Title Here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="http://localhost/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I've tried to use

```
return redirect()->route('/');
```

but sadly it doesn't work either.

I've also tried to throw 401 exception by using

```
abort(401)
```

And catch it in the exception handler and redirect from there (as i did so with the 404 and 500 exceptions and i was redirected successfully) but this does not work and i've got the same response message with the page sent as text in the response, so the problem is probably with redirecting from the middleware, can someone help me find the problem, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as a front-end engineer i've chosen to make a short-cut solution and redirect the user using react and axios so in the  middlewere i've just throw an httperror with status 401 (unauthorized) then caught it by axios as follows:
**My Middleware**

```
    if(!$isAuthenticated) {
      return abort(401);
   }
```

**react**

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_PREFIX
});

instance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        return response;
    },
    function(error) {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            window.location.replace("/");
        }
        return Promise.reject(error.response);
    }
);
```

Links that helped me: [github](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960)

Answer (score 0):

The  `return redirect('/');` will redirect the user to the public directory of your project.

Add name to the needed route like:

```
Route::get('/route', 'API\Controller@index')->name('route name');
```

Then you can redirect to the named route:

```
if(!$isAuthenticated) {
        return route('route name');
    }
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work, it gives me that error     "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::addHeaders() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, string given, called in F:\Web\work\monster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php on line 63" and when i searched about it i found irrelevant answers

Comment: @WeamAdel can you please add the route you are trying to redirect to, in your question.
and try to use the dd(); method inside the condition if(!$isAuthenticated) {
        dd('test');
    } to see if your code even try to execute what's inside the condition.

Comment: I've tried another solution and it is sending the status code and redirecting using react instead. Thank you so much for your time and effort sir :)